# Rust Nickel Server Not Working When Deployed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, security-groups

I created a simple backend server using the Rust "Nickel" framework by following the guide here: https://nickel-org.github.io/getting-started.html

I can run `cargo run` locally and hit the local endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:6767` via postman to get this response:

```
{
    message: "Hello! Sincerely, Jimbob's Rusty Nickel"
}
```

This is great, and I would like to deploy it live. I am using a micro aws ec2 instance with ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After I install cargo and run the app with `cargo run` I get the usual successful startup "waiting for requests" output:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6767
Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

I have the ports for my server open with these settings:

Inbound:

```
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0      
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0        
3000    tcp 0.0.0.0/0    
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0      
0-65535 tcp 0.0.0.0/0       
6767    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

Outbound:

```
All All  0.0.0.0/0       
6767    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

When I try to call to the live endpoint using either the ec2's Public DNS (IPv4) with port 6767 or the IPv4 Public IP with port 6767, I get this error response:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://3.83.65.51:6767.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```